# Get Euro (€) sign by old MacBook keyboard (Finnish)

Tags: xubuntu, keyboard-layout, shortcut-keys

I have the € sign printed on <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd>, but the combination gives a different character that is "¤". I am using "Finnish (Macintosh)" keyboard layout, and I tried "Apple", "Apple Laptop", "Generic 105-key (Intl) PC"  and "MacBook/MacBook Pro (Intl)" keyboard model in Xfce keyboard settings. Other keys seem to work fine. How to fix?

Workaround: Use compose key (Multi_key) and press <kbd>e</kbd> and then <kbd>=</kbd>. See other options at https://www.x.org/releases/X11R7.7/doc/libX11/i18n/compose/en_US.UTF-8.html

Workaround 2: <kbd>right alt</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd> (which is the similar key combination as standard keyboard has for €: <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd> + <kbd>e</kbd>). However, if I change keyboard settings, it might not work before new login for some odd reason. This worked with "MacBook/MacBook Pro (Intl)" keyboard setting at least.

(You might need to close the keyboard settings dialog, at least, to get the settings in effect.)

BTW <kbd>right Alt</kbd> + <kbd>4</kbd> prints Dollar sign "$".

The computer is [Apple MacBook "Core 2 Duo" 2.4 13" (Unibody)](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook/specs/macbook-core-2-duo-2.4-aluminum-13-late-2008-unibody-specs.html) having Finnish keyboard.

Comment: What is the other character? What keyboard layout are you using in settings? Please [edit] your question to include this information.

Comment: [Bug #1785387](https://launchpad.net/bugs/1785387) filed.